# How to make the question about when recruiters should call candidates clear again?

Tags: support, closed-questions, offtopic, scope

[When should recruiters call candidates instead of emailling?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/96871/26826)

Two person (Daniel, Lilienthal) agree that this question can be reopen if there is some improvements. Which bits are unclear, and how to improve them?

Interestingly, Lilienthal initially thinks that my question asks for something that strangers on the internet impossibly figure out, but later agrees that my point is fair. Why do they think that? I want to put myself in their shoes.